# Cargar imagen para reconocimiento de caracteres

Tags: javascript, html, tesseract

Necesito cargar con un `input` una imagen para procesarla con `tesseract`, pero una vez que la tengo cargada el botón "Procesar imagen" no lo envía a la función en `js` para hacer el reconocimiento, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title> OCR DEMO</title>

</head>

<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>

<script>  

        function cargar()
        {
            var myImage= document.getElementById('userImage');

            Tesseract.recognize(myImage).then(function(result){

            console.log(result.text);

            alert(result.text);

            });
        }



        </script>

<body>


                <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <input type="file" name="photo" id="userImage"  required>

                        <button  class="btn btn-primary btn-round" onclick="cargar()">Procesar imagen</button>

                </form>




</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

En principio, debes pasar la url, y no el elemento img como argumento, es decir `document.getElementById('userImage').src` y aquí te dejo un ejemplo funcional:

```js
const {
  TesseractWorker
} = Tesseract;
const worker = new TesseractWorker();

const myImage = document.getElementById('userImage').src;
const texto = document.getElementById('text');

worker
  .recognize(myImage)
  .progress((p) => {
    //console.log('progress', p);
    texto.innerText = "procesando .... va a tardar un poco";
  })
  .then(({
    text
  }) => {
    texto.innerText = text;
    worker.terminate();
  });
```

```css
img{
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js@v2.0.0-alpha.13/dist/tesseract.min.js'></script>
<img id="userImage" src="https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png" />
<p id="text"></p>
```

Comment: ME DA ERROR EN ESTA LINEA "const worker = new TesseractWorker();" ME DICE: "TESSERACTWORKER IS NOT A CONTRUCTOR"